# sed/awk to take first part of 'words'

Tags: awk, sed

I am trying to learn sed/awk and I am planning to use it on the following task. I have a command which prints out a list of files (possibly more than one per line) like the following:

```
--- /section/1 ---
appname1/detail1/something appname1/detail2/somethingelse another/app/2.0
sillyapp/details/here  bug/2.5
--- /section2/details/here ---
apname2/3.2.5  apname2/3.2.6 apname3/something.0.4/here
```

and I would like to do two things:

(1) Use sed to take *only* the first parts of the files (from ' ' to '/') so that we would have

```
--- /section/1 ---
appname1 appname1 another
sillyapp  bug
--- /section2/details/here ---
apname2 apname2 apname3
```

(2) use awk (I think?) to find out how many times each app is listed so we could have

```
appname1: 2
another: 1
sillyapp: 1
bug: 1
apname2: 2
apname3: 1
```

Can sed/awk be used for this? If so, can someone give detailed instructions as to how to accomplish each (any why it works)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use grep with `-o` to extract just the matches, and `-P` to get the perl-compatible regexes:

```
grep -Po '(^|\s)\K\w+(?=/)' file | sort | uniq -c
```

```
  1 another
  2 apname2
  1 apname3
  2 appname1
  1 bug
  1 sillyapp
```

That regex is:

```
(^|\s)  # either the beginning of the line, or a space
\K      # forget about what came before (i.e. don't remember the space)
\w+     # some word characters
(?=/)   # the next character is a slash (look-ahead)
```

---

with `sed`: I'm not a guru, but I came up with this:

```
sed -nr '/^---/d; s/(^| +)([^/]+)[^ ]+/\2 /g; H; ${x;s/\n//g;s/ $//; s/ /\n/g;p}' file
```

```
appname1
appname1
another
sillyapp
bug
apname2
apname2
apname3
```

That is

```
sed -nr '          # -n suppress printing; -r enable extended regular expressions
    /^---/d                      # delete "header" lines
    s/(^| +)([^/]+)[^ ]+/\2 /g   # extract the words you want, add a trailing space
    H                            # append this transformed line to the hold space
    ${                           # on the last line of input:
        g                        # bring the hold space contents into the pattern space
        s/\n//g                  # remove newlines
        s/ $//                   # remove a trailing space
        s/ /\n/g                 # change spaces into newlines
        p                        # and, finally, print the results
    }
' file
```

Following this, add `| sort | uniq -c` as above

Comment: Here is an gawk way you could add(if you wanted :)) `gawk -vRS=" +|\n+" -F"/" '{$1!~/^($|-)/&&a[$1]++}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]}'`